# Find the points where the function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a finite set and define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x\in X$},\\
0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

At which points $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is $f$ continuous?

I think the function is continuous at the points $c$ where $c$ is strictly greater than $\sup(X)$, or where $c$ is strictly less than $\inf(X)$, because at these points $f(x)$ equals zero.

I am not sure with what happens when $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is between the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $X$, I think that if there are intervals within the set $X$ than the points $c$ strictly between these intervals would also be continuous, but I don't know how to express that formally.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Notice that $X$ is *discrete*. Let $x \in X$. What happens at $x$? What about at $x - \epsilon$ if you know $x -\epsilon \not \in X$?

Comment: Try to see why the function is continuous at $c$ if and only if $c$ is not in $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f$ is discontinuous at every point of $X$ and continuous at every point of $\Bbb R\setminus X$. To see this, suppose $x\in X$. Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Since $X$ is finite, for every $\delta > 0$, the interval $(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ contains a point $y\notin X$, and $|f(y) - f(x)| = |0 - 1| = 1 > \varepsilon$. Hence, $f$ is discontinuous at $x$.

If $c\notin X$, then given $\varepsilon > 0$, set $\delta$ to be the smallest of the numbers $|c - x|$, $x\in X$. For all $y$, $|y - c| < \delta$ implies $y\notin X$, and thus $|f(y) - f(c)| = |0 - 0| = 0 < \varepsilon$. Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose x is a real not in X. Finite sets in IR are closed sets, so one can find an open interval V in IR containing x such that V does not intersect X. On V, f(y)=0.So, f is continuous at x. Now, if z is in X, one can find a sequence (z_n)of reals from outside X which converges to z, but then (f(z_n)) is the constant sequence (0) and it does not converge to 1=f(z).

Therefore, f is continuous only on IR-X.